# How can I roll back network-manager w/o network available

Tags: networking, apt, updates, dns

On a KUbuntu 16.04 system I believe that the latest update to network-manager may have broken dns.

Using apt list I found:

```
#-> apt list -a network-manager
Listing... Done
network-manager/xenial-updates,now 1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 amd64 [installed]
network-manager/xenial-security 1.2.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.4 amd64
network-manager/xenial 1.1.93-0ubuntu4 amd64
```

1) Does network-manager 1.1.93-0ubuntu4 amd64 still exist on disk ?

2) If so, how can I reinstall it ?

3) I'm assuming that afterward I can use 'apt-mark hold' to prevent future updates until the problem has been resolved ?

Thanks